# Word request: what's a startup-like synonym for the word "grapevine"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, homonyms, compound-words

Single word request: Grapevine is a word used to describe the spread of rumors via spoken communication. Can you think of a similar 2-syllable, startup-like synonym for grapevine?

I've tried a search of the thesaurus and of the words I've seen, the most fitting are: Hearsay, Gossip, Chatter.

However, this doesn't quite fit the theme of disseminating information on a vine, i.e. I want the connotation that you are "in the loop" rather than plainly a word describing gossip. Compound words, 2-syllable words, homonyms, palindromes and double letter words (e.g. Google and Twitter), or words you can "verbalize" (e.g. "Googled") are preferable!

Thanks so much!

Comment: What do you mean by ‘startup-like’?

Comment: @Spagirl It's a bit of a vague term, but roughly I mean: compound words, 2-syllable words, homonyms, palindromes and double letter words (e.g. Google and Twitter), or words that you can verbalize like Google.

Answer (score 1):

An appropriate *verb* for this would be to say something like the following:

> I [**planted**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/plant) a rumour.

From Merriam-Webster:

> **1 a** : to put or set in the ground for growth
>   // *plant* seeds
>   **1 b** : to set or sow with seeds or plants

This not only follows the grapevine analogy, but implies that you *started* the rumour, and that you are also in on it—as well as possibly tending it after the fact so that it will grow appropriately.